# Gantry on Joomla : How to change the way master-ie8.css is loaded?

Tags: css, joomla

I am working on a website which is using the Gantry framework v4.1.10 on `Joomla 2.5`.
We activated the `Nginx` cache on the server.

My problem is that `the master-ie8.css` is loaded by php, so with `Nginx` cache if the first person going on the website is on IE8, everyone will get the `master-ie8.css` loaded until the next `Nginx` cache purge...

So I would like to remove the call to master-ie8.css by PHP and replace it by the standard

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<![endif]-->
```

Do you have any idea about how can I do it ?
And if it is possibel to do it with changing the gantry core, so I will not loose it in the next gantry update..

Thanks for your help.

---

**EDIT** - I found the solution

---

I found the solution, so if someone have the same problem, the solution is quite simple :

- Rename the master-ie8.css by something like style-ie8.css file in /templates/YOURTEMPLATE/css folder
- Do the same for the master-ie9.css

=> The master-ie8.css et master-ie9.css will not bve loaded

- You now just have to edit the index.php file of your template /templates/YOURTEMPLATE/index.php
- Manually add the following lines just before  :

  `<!--[if IE 8]>
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/YOURTEMPLATE/css/style-ie8.css" />
   <![endif]-->
   <!--[if IE 9]>
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/YOURTEMPLATE/css/style-ie9.css" />
   <![endif]-->`

=> The css files for IE8 and IE9 will be loaded on client side by the browser so the server cache will not be a problem anymore.

Comment: Dude be careful for the question formatting next time, an important piece of your question is hidden ;)

Comment: Thanks, I will be careful next time :)

Comment: you should add this answer in the answer box below and accept it ;)